# Are these characterizations of a singular point equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$ Let $X=V(f) \subseteq \P^n$ be a hypersurface over an algebraically closed field, let $(1:p) \in X \cap \mathbb{A}_0^n$, and let $\tilde{f}(t)=f(1,t)\in k[t_1,\dots, t_n]$ be the dehomogenization of $f$. Are the following statements equivalent?

1. $(1:p)$ is a singular point of $X$.
2. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}(1:p)=0$ for all $i=0,\dots,n$.
3. $\frac{\partial \tilde{f}}{\partial t_i}(p)=0$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$.

My attempt at a proof:

It is clear to me that for all $i=1,\dots, n$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}(1:p)=\frac{\partial \tilde{f}}{\partial t_i}(p)$. So it is clear that $2 \Rightarrow 3$. For the reverse implication, it seems like we would need to show that for any homogeneous polynomial $f$, if $f(1:p)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}(1:p)=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_0}(1:p)=0$.

I am aware that $1 \iff 2$ (e.g. Shafarevich basic algebraic geometry chapter 2 section 1 exercise 12), so don't worry about showing this implication.

---

If this statement is NOT true, then I probably have a follow-up question about how this jives with the fact that we can view the Zariski tangent space to $X$ at $(1:p)$ in two (I think equivalent) ways: as the standard affine Zariski tangent space to $X \cap \mathbb{A}_0^n$ at $p$, and as the affine Zariski tangent space of $\text{cone}(X)$ at $(1,p)$, quotiented by the subspace $\text{span}{(1,p)}$, but I'll leave out this rant for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. First, we note that taking derivatives with respect to any $t_i$ with $i\neq 0$ commutes with dehomogenization, so $\frac{df}{dx_i}(1:p)=\frac{d\tilde{f}}{dx_i}(p)$ for $i\neq 0$. So it remains to see that $\frac{df}{dx_0}(1:p)=0$.

For any homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$, we have that $d\cdot f = \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i\frac{df}{dt_i}$. Now we evaluate at $(1:p)$: by the condition that $(1:p)$ is on our variety, the left hand side vanishes. By the condition that $\frac{d\tilde{f}}{dx_i}=\frac{df}{dx_i}$ for $i\neq 0$ from the above paragraph and the assumptions of (3), we see that every term on the right hand side which isn't $\frac{df}{dx_0}$ will also vanish after evaluating at $(1:p)$, so $\frac{df}{dx_0}$ must vanish when evaluating at $(1:p)$ as well, and the claim is proven.

Comment: Thank you! The key insight I was missing is your third sentence: For $f$ homogeneous of degree $m$, $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}(x) x_i=mf(x)$ for any input $x$, so $d_x f := \sum_{i=0}^{n} (t_i-x_i) \frac{df}{dt_i}(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n} t_i\frac{df}{dt_i}(x)$ for any $[x] \in V(f)$.